# Can I put a breakpoint in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, debugging, breakpoints

Is there a way to suspend the execution of the shell script to inspect the state of the environment or execute random commands?

Answer (score 4):

`alias` combined with `eval` gives you basic functionality of breakpoints in calling context:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

alias breakpoint='
    while read -p"Debugging(Ctrl-d to exit)> " debugging_line
    do
        eval "$debugging_line"
    done'

f(){
    local var=1
    breakpoint
    echo $'\n'"After breakpoint, var=$var"
}

f
```

At the breakpoint, you can input

```
echo $var
```

followed by

```
var=2
```

then Ctrl-d to exit from breakpoint.

Due to `eval` in the while loop, use with caution.

Comment: This approach won't work if stdin/stdout/stderr haven't been redirected. Potentially you could preserve the current FDs and set them back to the TTY for the duration of the `while` loop.

Comment: @psmears Script is there just to give an idea. Much needs to be done for it to be usable in real situations.

Comment: Fair enough - just pointing it out as someone who didn't realise this limitation could otherwise get quite confused :)

Comment: Does `breakpoint` need to be an alias? Is there some reason it couldn't just be a function...? EDIT: I guess @yurios answer is an answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69590536/11798417

Comment: @mainmachine You might try using `function`, but in this particular case, `alias` is much easier/better.

Comment: @Philippe - What makes it easier or better? I'm not being pedantic - if there's a tangible reason why it's better I think that's important to include here. My first inclination would be to use a function as that's my preference, but if there's a practical reason that an alias is a better choice then it goes beyond personal preference.

Comment: @mainmachine if you use function, breakpoint will be run in its own function scope, whereas defined as alias, it's run in the calling function scope. That's why I put "calling context" in my answer.

Comment: @Philippe - of course, preserving the environment. There was indeed a subtle yet significant difference I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bash or shell scripts do not have such debugging capabilities as other programming languages like Java, Python, etc.

We can put the `echo "VAR_NAME=$VAR_NAME"` command in the code where we want to log the variable value.

Also, a little bit more flexible solution is to put this code somewhere at the beginning in the shell script we want to debug:

```
function BREAKPOINT() {
  BREAKPOINT_NAME=$1
  echo "Enter breakpoint $BREAKPOINT_NAME"
  set +e
  /bin/bash
  BREAKPOINT_EXIT_CODE=$?
  set -e
  if [[ $BREAKPOINT_EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Continue after breakpoint $BREAKPOINT_NAME"
  else
    echo "Terminate after breakpoint $BREAKPOINT_NAME"
    exit $BREAKPOINT_EXIT_CODE
  fi
}

export -f BREAKPOINT
```

and then later, at the line of code where we need to break we invoke this function like this:

```
# some shell script here
BREAKPOINT MyBreakPoint
# and some other shell script here
```

So then the BREAKPOINT function will log some output then launch `/bin/bash` where we can run any `echo` or some other shell command we want. When we want to continue running the rest of the shell script (release breakpoint) we just need to execute `exit` command. If we need to terminate script execution we would run `exit 1` command.

Comment: This might be helpful to you: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/debug-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

There exist solutions like [bash-debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rogalmic.bash-debug).
A poor-man's solution which works for me is the interactive shell.
By adding three lines of code, you can introspect and alter variables as follows:

Let's assume, that you have the script `test.bash`

```bash
A=FOO
export B=BAR
echo $A
echo $B
```

```
$ test.bash
FOO
BAR
```

If you add an interactive shell at line 3, you can look around and inspect variables which have been exported before:

```
A=FOO
export B=BAR
bash -c "$SHELL"
echo $A
echo $B
```

```
$ test.bash
$ echo $A

$ echo $B
BAR
$ exit
FOO
BAR
```

If you want to see all variables in your interactive shell, you have to add `set -a` to the preamble of your script, such that all variables and functions are exported:

```
set -a
A=FOO
export B=BAR
bash -c "$SHELL"
echo $A
echo $B
```

```
$ test.bash
$ echo $A
FOO
$ echo $B
BAR
$ exit
FOO
BAR
```

Note, that you cannot change the variables in your interactive shell. The only solution for me is to source an additional script of variables, which will be sourced rightafter the interactive shell

```
set -a
A=FOO
export B=BAR
bash -c "$SHELL"
source /tmp/var
echo $A
echo $B
```

```
$ test.bash
$ echo "export A=alice" > /tmp/var
$ echo "export B=bob" >> /tmp/var
$ exit
alice
bob
```